SQL Query to assign dates from Month and Week Columns
I have 2 tables like this
table1

table2

I'm trying to write a SQL query which will convert these month weeks into dates and assign it to each WTG sequentially, to get an output which looks like this:

I'm considering the dates like this:
W1-7,
W2-14,
W3-21,
W4-28,
W5-31/30
Any help is appreciated.

You need more details to join to get 1 to 1
    DECLARE @sNos AS TABLE (Sno INT)

INSERT INTO @sNos (Sno) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)

SELECT DISTINCT t1.Mid, t1.Pid, t1.WTG, 
DATEADD(DD, CASE 
        WHEN RIGHT(up.PmtWeek, 1) = 5 THEN DAY(DATEADD(DD, -1, DATEADD(MM, 1, CONVERT(DATE, FORMAT(up.Year, '0') + LEFT(up.PmtWeek, 3) + '01')))) 
        ELSE (RIGHT(up.PmtWeek, 1) * 7) END - 1, 
    CONVERT(DATE, FORMAT(up.Year, '0') + LEFT(up.PmtWeek, 3) + '01')) AS [Date]
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM t2) d
UNPIVOT(Pmt FOR PmtWeek IN (JanW1, JanW2, JanW3, JanW4, JanW5, FebW1, FebW2)) up
INNER JOIN @sNos n ON n.Sno BETWEEN 1 AND up.Pmt 
INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.Mid = up.Mid AND t1.Pid = up.Pid


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
